# PLAY Framework Integrating with Akka

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I'm trying to get this [tutorial](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.0/ScalaAkka)  to work but they seem to have an issue. I get an error in this piece of code:

```
(helloActor ? SayHello(name)).mapTo[String].map { message => Ok(message) }
```

> not found: value SayHello

It seems that `SayHello(name)` is not in the scope of the Application class.

Comment: You need to import `SayHello`.

Comment: @Ryan, thanks. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it. Can you explain why it needs to be imported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the `SayHello` class.  Since the class is defined in the companion object of `HelloActor`, it is not visible by default outside that object.